# Prevent returning $http get call response until all the data comes

Tags: angularjs

I am using a "$http" get call in factory and want to stop  returning the response to controler until all the data comes from the back end.(As it is asynchronous call, before getting all the data,codes next to the call execute.)I want, response will be returned when all data comes and then the next codes will be executed. How can I do that?

My controller is:

```
(
    function(){
        angular.module("module").controller("controller", ["$scope",   "FactoryName", function ($scope, FactoryName) {

        var getPrograms = function () {
            FactoryName.functionName()
               .then(
                      function (d) {                              
                              $scope.data = d.Data;                              
                      },
                       function (errResponse) {

                       }
               );
        }
      }])

  }()

)
```

Here is my factory:

```
angular.module("module").factory("FactoryName", ["$http", '$q', function   ($http, $q)   {
    return {
        functionName: function () {
            return $http.get("url")
                    .then(
                            function (response) {
                                return response.data;
                            },
                            function (errResponse) {
                                return $q.reject(errResponse);
                            }
                    );
            },
      };
}])
```

Comment: Put your code after `$scope.data = d.Data`

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't work....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your factory code by this one

```
angular.module("module").factory("FactoryName", ["$http", '$q', function($http, $q)   {
    return {
        functionName: function () {
            return $http.get("url");
            },
      };
}])
```

And your controller will be like this

```
(
    function(){
        angular.module("module").controller("controller", ["$scope",   "FactoryName", function ($scope, FactoryName) {

        var getPrograms = function () {
            FactoryName.functionName()
               .then(
                      function (response) {             
                          //request loaded
                          $scope.data = response.data; 
                          //Add code here..                             
                      },
                       function (errResponse) {
                          //handle errors
                       }
               );
        }
      }])

  }()

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this way in factory.

```
functionName: function () {
       var deferred = $q.defer();
       return $http.get("url")
       .then(function (response) {
             deferred.resolve(response.data);
        }, function (errResponse) {
             deferred.reject(errResponse);
        }
    );
   return deferred.promise;
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets re-write the factory a little differently -

```
angular.module("module").factory("FactoryName", ["$http", '$q', function   ($http, $q)   {
    return {
        functionName: function () {

           var defer = $q.defer();
           $http.get(URL)
           .success(function(res){
                defer.resolve(res);
           })
           .error(function(error, status){
               defer.reject(error)
           });
        return defer.promise;,
      };
}])
```